# Access to all checked RadGridView 's Rows via GridViewCheckBoxColumn (Telerik component)

Tags: c#, checkbox, gridview, telerik, radgridview

i want to access all checked row in RadGridView(Telerik component) via GridViewCheckBoxColumn. Note : User select checkbox at run time ...
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can access checkbox column like this:

```
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo item in radGridView1.Rows.ToList())
        {
            if(item.Cells[0].Value.Equals(true))
            {
                //dowhat you want
            }
        }
```

in "Cell[0]" the zero index is the index of checkbox column

Comment: thank you for reply ... i use your solution and got this error : "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
"
string s1 = "";
            foreach (GridViewRowInfo item in radGridView1.Rows.ToList())
            {
                if (item.Cells[0].Value.Equals(true))
                {
                    s1 += item.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

Comment: did you try that without adding your code? Remove your added code and check if there is still error?

Comment: Also i only see 3 columns in the picture, so make sure index 3 which you used is correct. @prorammer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one checkbox column in your grid, you can use the following code to access that value. If you have more than one column of that type, you might want to do some sort of name check or perhaps bind the grid to a model.

Note: Make sure to check for null values.

```
foreach (Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo rowInfo in reportGridView.Rows)
{
    foreach (Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellInfo cell in rowInfo.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.ColumnInfo.GetType() == typeof(Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCheckBoxColumn))
        {
            if (cell.Value != null && (bool)cell.Value == true)
            {
                // Some logic here to handle this ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```